# TablewView setAll of backing List resets selection but not focus

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm working on a Task-Manager like application, where the whole backing list of a TableView gets replaced by the result of periodically running a command line program. I'm using `setAll` to set the table view to the newest items. It works, but it resets the selection in the view.

Interestingly, the blue focus bar does not move, but a very small outline is shown on the first item of the table view after it was updated with `setAll`. I guess this is how the selected index is rendered.  When I use the arrow keys to navigate, the selection will jump periodically back to the first item of the list.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what do you expect if the complete data is reset? Clearing selection seems to be the right thingy. Your options: a) keep track of the selectedIndex, listen to data changes and if you detect a setAll, re-select the old index b) don't use setAll ... oops, just seeing your edit, so you already opted for b ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply! The new version works, but I still wonder why using `setAll` does reset the selection, but not the focus. I would expect both to be reset. If I could configure selection to behave as focus currently does, my problem would also be solved.

Comment: OK. BTW: I tried implementing option a, but could not get it to work. I think there might be some concurrency issues involved. I would get `IndexOutOfBounds` Exceptions with stacktraces that did not have any of my own code in there.

Comment: then stick to option b, nothing inherently bad in it and if it's working :) adding to my comments: looks like tableView selection is behaving as you expect it (it seems to keep the selectedItem if it is still contained, fx11), while list selection still has erratic behavior. BTW: there are still tons of bugs around selection/focus/anchor for all controls that have a selectionModel ... improved over the years, though

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Java 8, maybe I'll try 11. For now I'll stick to option b then :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, but I'm sure there is a better way. I manually calculate the difference between the new and the previous state. Then I call the removeAll, and addAll methods respectively:

```
object PortBindingLock

private fun reloadBindings() {
    synchronized(PortBindingLock) {
        val previous = this.portBindings.toSet()
        val current = processService.processPortBindings().toSet()
        val toRemove = Sets.difference(previous, current)
        val toAdd = Sets.difference(current, previous)
        this.portBindings.removeAll(toRemove)
        this.portBindings.addAll(toAdd)
    }

}
```